Is accessing outer multidimensional array using reference to inner array defined in C?
Consider the following piece of code:
void process(int *);

int func(void) {
    int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    process(arr[0]);
    return arr[1][0];
}

Assume the function process is implemented in Assembly language.
As explained in Is accessing an element of a multidimensional array out of bounds undefined behavior?, it is undefined behaviour to access the element arr[1][0] using arr[0][2], which through pointer arithmetic should point to the same memory location.
Can the C compiler compiling the above code assume that arr[1][0] is unchanged after the call to process and hence e.g. optimise the last line to return 3; since the process function only gets access to arr[0][0] and arr[0][1]?
But maybe it is not undefined behaviour if the compiler assumes process internally first casts arr[0] to an int[2][2] pointer, similar to how the common container_of macro gets access to a pointer to the struct using a pointer to a member value so thus the compiler would not be allowed to perform the optimisation above?

container_of is from the Linux kernel, right?  Linux is not written in standard C, but depends on compiler extensions and Posix (which is not part of standard C either).

The compiler may optimise in any way that it chooses, if the result is correct. If a function contains undefined behaviour, then the result is undefined anyway, so the compiler may code as if the function process() is conformant.

None known compiler will not do such optimizations

@BoP container_of can be implemented in a way compliant with C standard. Whether it works is quite debatable due to the ambiguous way the standard is written.

You are simply dealing with C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3) and the sections @EricPostpischil mentions in his (now deleted) answer. His explanation makes clear there is no aliasing violation in your code. The answer to your question is simple "No". The parameter of int * makes no guarantee that the contents are not modified in process(), and there is no way for the compiler to assume otherwise unless you change the declaration to restrict modification.


Can the C compiler compiling the above code assume that arr[1][0] is unchanged after the call to process and hence e.g. optimise the last line to return 3; since the process function only gets access to arr[0][0] and arr[0][1]?

I suppose that the C compiler cannot assume that arr[1][0] is unchanged after the call to process(arr[0]), and hence it cannot optimize the last line to return 3.
The array arr[2][2] looks like a memory:
arr[0][0] -> | 1  |  Memory address: base + 0
arr[0][1] -> | 2  |  Memory address: base + sizeof(int)
arr[1][0] -> | 3  |  Memory address: base + 2 * sizeof(int)
arr[1][1] -> | 4  |  Memory address: base + 3 * sizeof(int)

When passing arr[0] to the process function, I suppose the compiler knows that arr[0] is a pointer to int, but the process function could access arr[1][0] because arr is a contiguous block of memory. And further the compiler probably cannot assume that arr[1][0] is unchanged after the call to process. So that C compiler might cannot optimize the last line to directly return arr[1][0].

how the common container_of macro gets access to a pointer to the struct using a pointer to a member value so thus the compiler would not be allowed to perform the optimisation above?

In the container_of macro, all pointer arithmetic is done on compatible types. It does not violate strict aliasing. I suppose the container_of macro follows the strict aliasing rule. so, the container_of macro techniques  prevent this compiler optimizations.
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))


The compiler, supposed to read data from an array. That is what language demands. So you should not worry to much about the bug you expecting.
Substitution of array access with constant is not a language specific, but compiler specific. And most current compilers are smart enough to do it correctly.
To get a better picture, try to compile this code:
#include <stdio.h>

void process(int *p) {
    p[2] = -1;
}
void process2(int *p);


int main() {
    int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    printf("%d\n", arr[1][0]);
    process(arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1][0]);

    int arr2[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};
    printf("%d\n", arr2[1][0]);
    process2(arr2[0]);
    printf("%d\n", arr2[1][0]);

    return 0;
}

Without any optimization (gcc -S foo.c) you can have two arrays on the stack with reading from the array all four times.
But once you turn on the optimizer (gcc -S -O1 foo.c), you can see a full disappearance of first array, printing of constants in first two printf's, defining an array on the stack for arr2, then printf of a constant, call to process2 and finally printf from the array.

I was manly interested in whether or not a compiler is allowed to perform the substitution in my scenario according to the C standard. I don't care that much about what some popular current existing compilers do. Because who knows if a future compiler does it but all current ones don't.

@Emil The answer is "no, not allowed". As I said in the first part of my answer: "supposed to read data from an array. That is what language demands." Sorry if it was not clear enough.

@WhiteOwl Nothing in your answer addresses whether or not process, if it was written in C, would be able to perform some action that would change the defined result of func to be anything other than 3 without UB (which would be necessary for the transformation to not be allowed). For example in C++ there is no way to do that without UB. (Although there seems to be a defect at the moment that makes it less clear.) The C standard is, as far as I can tell, much less clear on this.
